# Identifier Error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the count on the number of times "Lenore" is in the poem along with a total word count. I'm getting the error on line 13, please help. I'm very new and can't seem to grasp how to order the code correctly.

```
package theraven;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class lenore {

    Scanner myscanner = new Scanner("/Users/karaleamann/Desktop/theraven.txt");

    public int countWord(String Lenore, File"/Users/karaleamann/Desktop/theraven.txt") {
        int count = 0;
        while (myscanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String nextToken = myscanner.next();

            if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(Lenore))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int countAll() {
        File file = new File("/Users/karaleamann/Desktop/theraven.txt");
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(lenore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.next();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + count);
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: There also seems to be a problem with calling on the method that's counting Lenore. In the main I have:lenore myLenore = new lenore(); 
 myLenore.countWord(); but I'm not sure what to put in the ()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in Java:

```
public int countWord(String Lenore, File "/Users/karaleamann/Desktop/theraven.txt")
```

I believe you meant this instead:

```
public int countWord(String Lenore, File theFile)
```

The actual value for the parameter `theFile` must be provided when *calling* the method, not during parameter declaration, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't have a Main method which is the one needed to execute a class. Second you define the method countWord in an invalid way.

Change your class name to Lenore camelCase pattern, class names should have name with upper case first letter

```
public int countWord(String Lenore, File "/Users/karaleamann/Desktop/theraven.txt")
```

You can't do that. You have to pass just parameters

```
it would be something like:

public int countWord(String lenore, File file){
                            //^ variables name should be 
                            //      in camelCase
                                        //^you pass a File variable 
                                        //   to the method.
```

But since you define a scanner on your class you dont need to pass a file to this method, you need to change the definition of your scanner like this:

```
new Scanner(new File("/Users/karaleamann/Desktop/theraven.txt"));
```

Then your method `countWord` should be `countWord(String lenora)`

You have two methods that are doing nothing. One is using the scanner but it was never called. And the other you are not finding anything at all.

Your `countAll` method is the closest one to your solution, so lets stick with it.

You should change this part

```
 while(sc.hasNext()){
     String lineText = sc.next();
     if ( lineText.indexOf("Lenora")>-1 ){
      count++;   
     }
 }
```

Then create a main method to start your program

```
public static void main(String [] args){
     Lenore l = new Lenore();
     l.countAll();
}
```

Off course that is not the ideal code. You have to evolve it to a more logical code. Separating the tasks, creating resources only as needed. But it should work for now.